# jquery icons in jquery tabs problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

when i put jquery icon on my website it looks fine, but when i put icon inside jquery tab, icon image is moved few pixels left
has anybody solved that problem already?
thnx!

Comment: This question is very vague. It would benefit from an example or some sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably best off installing the Firefox plugin Firebug and inspecting the item. That way you will be able to see all the styles attached to the icon and what might be the cause of it moving.